# Referring entities from library to another library in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistent

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6.Final with JPA and Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE in my project with Java Configuration.

I have two jar files.  module1.jar and module2.jar.  module1.jar has some entities
and module2 has some entities. I can't use the module1.jar entity in module2.jar without using
persistent.xml and

```
<jar-file>module1.jar</jar-file>
```

Is it necessary to have persistent.xml as I am using

entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.mydomain") to scan all the entities from all jar files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the error in my code. I was setting the packagesToScan after the entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to use the `persistence.xml` if you are configuring Spring's `entityManagerFactoryBean` with `setPackagesToScan()`.

From [New Features and Enhancements in Spring 3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e1495):

> 3.1.12 JPA EntityManagerFactory bootstrapping without persistence.xml
>
> In standard JPA, persistence units get defined through META-INF/persistence.xml files in specific jar files which will in turn get searched for @Entity classes. In many cases, persistence.xml does not contain more than a unit name and relies on defaults and/or external setup for all other concerns (such as the DataSource to use, etc). For that reason, Spring 3.1 provides an alternative: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean accepts a 'packagesToScan' property, specifying base packages to scan for @Entity classes. This is analogous to AnnotationSessionFactoryBean's property of the same name for native Hibernate setup, and also to Spring's component-scan feature for regular Spring beans. **Effectively, this allows for XML-free JPA setup** at the mere expense of specifying a base package for entity scanning: a particularly fine match for Spring applications which rely on component scanning for Spring beans as well, possibly even bootstrapped using a code-based Servlet 3.0 initializer.